# How can I get constant value in struts.xml into annotation @Result of the Struts 2?

Tags: struts2, annotations, constants

I want get a value constants declared into struts.xml
Example

```
<constant name="my.name" value="William Miranda de Jesus"></constant>
```

In my Action, I have a annotation for my results

```
@Result(name="input",  location="/etc/htdocs/_templates/${my.name}/error.vm", type="velocity")
```

Is this possible ? What Do I need to configure ?

Thanks

Comment: Hii, I am also searching the same, can anyone suggest on this....